# IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for java.util.List<ModelClass> when using SimpleXmlConverter with retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit

**Usage**

```
private Retrofit mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://www.w3schools.com")
                .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

**Service class**

```
public interface Food{
 @GET("/xml/simple.xml")
    Call<List<FoodId>> getFoodIdType();
}
```

**Model class**

```
@Root(name = "Food")
    public class Food{
        @Element(name = "id")
        private int id;
        @Element(name = "description")
        private String description;
        public Food(){

        }
}
```

**Gradle config**

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.0.0') {
    exclude module: 'stax'
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
    exclude module: 'xpp3'
}
```

**Side note:**
I was able to make it work with GsonConverterfactory, when used a different url.

Comment: Changing @Root(name = "Food") to @Root(name = "food") might help....

Answer (score 2):

Changing `@Root(name = "Food")` to `@Root(name = "food")` might help. And your whole model class should be like this:

```
@Root(name = "breakfast_menu") 

public class BreakFastMenu {

    @ElementList(inline = true)
    List<Food> foodList;
}


@Root(name = "food")
class Food {

    @Element(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Element(name = "price")
    String price;

    @Element(name = "description")
    String description;

    @Element(name = "calories")
    String calories;
}
```